# Git fetch on master breaks

Tags: git, git-fetch

I am trying to run below command after shallow clone.

```
//Run first - Passes
git fetch --depth 100 --update-head-ok origin master:remotes/origin/master

// Run next - Fails
git fetch --depth 100 --update-head-ok origin topic/poc:remotes/origin/topic/poc
```

It fails with reason

```
fatal: git fetch-pack: expected shallow list
```

First fetch always works, but second fecth fails. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Does it also fail for depth 50, 10 or 2?

Comment: @hlovdal - Updated the question. First fetch always passes, second one starts the fails. Even if i run it reverse order.